# How to setup Raspberry pi 4 camera in headless mode?

Tags: linux, ssh, camera, headless, raspberry-pi4

I was working on a project in which I was using Raspberry pi 4 Model-B in it's headless mode, and now I want to connect a camera to it but I was unable to do so.
When I run `vcgencmd get_camera` the output was

```
supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0
```

I don't understand why is it showing `supported=0`?
I then booted up my pi on raspbian os with desktop GUI and camera worked totally fine with no issue so I concluded that there is issue in headless mode itself or may be I'm doing something wrong.

After browsing some of the forums I found this [article](https://www.hackster.io/sridhar-rajagopal/raspberry-pi-high-quality-camera-headless-setup-tips-37903c) where author talks about how to setup RPI camera with raspberry pi in it's headless mode where I found nothing much helpful.

My raspberry pi camera model is `Rev 1.3`

Also note that I'm using SSH to exchange information between Pi and my Desktop

And when I re-enabled Legacy camera it is showing this
[image]

Comment: Most likely camera interface is not enabled in the config. https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html

Comment: Ofcourse, I enabled it!

Comment: This article may be of interest https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bullseye-camera-system/

Comment: I got this working.  You need to disable legacy and do the workaround at https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=323547